# Comparing records by multiple columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table similar to this:

| ID | device_id | adv_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123qwe | NULL |
| 2 | NULL | 345qwe |
| 3 | 123qwe | 345qwe |
| 4 | qaw345 | cvb456 |

I need to return count() of unique records by comparing records by multiple columns (in this example device_id and adv_id). So for example table count() of unique records should be 2, as records 1, 2 and 3 should be counted as 1 unique record, and record 4 is second unique record.

Edit1. There could be duplicates of records, though those records should still counted as 1.

| ID | device_id | adv_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123qwe | NULL |
| 2 | NULL | 345qwe |
| 3 | NULL | 345qwe |
| 4 | 123qwe | 345qwe |
| 5 | qaw345 | cvb456 |
| 6 | qaw345 | cvb456 |
| 7 | qaw345 | cvb456 |

Count: 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM test t1
  JOIN test t2 ON COALESCE(t1.device_id, t2.device_id) = COALESCE(t2.device_id, t1.device_id)
              AND COALESCE(t1.adv_id, t2.adv_id) = COALESCE(t2.adv_id, t1.adv_id)
  GROUP BY COALESCE(t1.device_id, t2.device_id), COALESCE(t1.adv_id, t2.adv_id)
  )
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM cte;
```

| COUNT(*) |
| --- |
| 2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/h_DX741n)